# Run Javascript Game from HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I have followed a tutorial on making a simple HTML canvas game ([link here](http://www.lostdecadegames.com/how-to-make-a-simple-html5-canvas-game/)).  The game is saved in a javascript file, an I'm not sure how to test it out. I looked around and found that it should be run from an html page, so I wrote it this so far:

```
<html>
<head>

<script language="javascript" src="main.js" type="text/javascript"/>
</script>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

This does nothing, which I expected. However, I'm not sure what to do in order to run this. I'd appreciate any input in this. 
Thanks

**edit***
It's come down to an error in the javascript file. Below is my code:

```
//canvas
var canvas=document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width=512;
canvas.height=480;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

//background img
var bgready=false;
var bgimage=new Image();
bgimage.onload=function(){
    bgready=true;
};
bgimage.src="images/bg_space.png";
//player img
var playerready=false;
var playerimage=new Image();
playerimage.onload=function(){
    playerready=true;
};
playerimage.src="images/spr_player.png";
//enemy img
var enemyready=false;
var enemyimage=new Image();
enemyimage.onload=function(){
    enemyready=true;
};
enemyimage.src="images/spr_enemy1.png";

//objects
var player={
    speed:256
};

var enemy={};
var kills=0;

//handle keys
var keysdown={};

addEventListener("keydown",function(e){
    keysdown[e.keycode]=true;
},false);

addEventListener("keyup",function(e){
    delete keysdown[e.keyCode];
},false);

//reset
var reset=function(){
    player.x=canvas.width/2;
    player.y=canvas.height/2

    enemy.x=32+(Math.random()*(canvas.width-64));
    enemy.y=32+(Math.random()*(canvas.height-64));
};

//update
var update=function(modifier){
if (38 in keysdown){
    player.y-=player.speed*modifier;//up
}
if (40 in keysdown){
    player.y+=player.speed*modifier;//down
}
if (37 in keysdown){
    player.x-=player.speed*modifier;//left
}
if (39 in keysdown){
    player.x+=player.speed*modifier;//right
}

if(
    player.x<=(enemy.x+32) 
    && enemy.x<=(player.x+32) 
    && player.y<=(enemy.y+32) 
    && enemy.y<=(player.y+32)
    ){
        ++kills;
        reset();
}
};

//render
var render=function(){
if (bgready){
    ctx.drawImage(bgimage,0,0);
}

if (playerready){
    ctx.drawImage(playerimage,player.x,player.y);
}

if (enemyready){
    ctx.drawImage(enemyimage,enemy.x,enemy.y);
}

//score
ctx.fillStyle="rgb(250,250,250)";
ctx.font="24px Helvetica";
ctx.textAlign="left";
ctx.textBaseline="top";
ctx.fillText("kills: "+kills,32,32);
};

//mainloop
var main=function(){
var now=Date.now();
var delta=now-then;

update(delta/1000);
render();

then=now;
};

//init
reset();
var then=Date.now();
setInterval(main,1);
```

I've looked over both my script and the tutorial script at least 7 times now. I did find that I was loading the images wrong, but now all it does is display the images. I can't move the player at all.

Comment: is `main.js` https://github.com/lostdecade/simple_canvas_game/blob/master/js/game.js ?

Comment: That's all that their page loads up.

Comment: Put it between the <body> </body> tags and git rid of the language="javascript" attribute.

Comment: I'm guessing he forgot to download /images.

Comment: actually I didn't copy his code, I wrote it myself and made my own images. also I tried putting in the body and getting rid of the language attribute, and still nothing.

Comment: here's my html code: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script src="main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>`

Comment: Well then there is an error in your javascript :)

Comment: Go to https://github.com/lostdecade/simple_canvas_game download that and run that index.html if that works replace the game.js file with yours and run it. You'll see there will be an error somewhere.

Comment: check your browser's html/js inspector. You would see warnings/errors there.

Comment: Exactly, use the browser's tools and check if any errors are caught. Or provide link to your source code so people can help you find the issue. The html code only tells us that you tried to run the javascript without success.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem might be in the HTML code. 
I'm pretty sure the correct syntax would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

Or if that doesn't solve it, just make a `<script>` tag after the `</body>` tag, and paste all the code in there.

Comment: While this is more correct syntax, it does not actually solve the problem, which the OP solved himself (see his edit).